# Failing to install the Grunt command line interface

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am currently having trouble installing the grunt command line interface, i get a whole lot of errors on the log when I try and install it using instructions off a tutorial website. I just added node.js from a package I downloaded off their website. Any help would be appreciated?

I used the following command as detailed on the roots WordPress instructions page

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and this error message was returned

```
npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock grunt-cli, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! at unlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:44:11)
npm ERR! at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:30:5)
npm ERR! at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local.js:47:20
npm ERR! at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:30:7
npm ERR! at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:167:38
npm ERR! at OpenReq.Req.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR! at OpenReq.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:64:22)
npm ERR! at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this entire log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/jonbeech
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/jonbeech/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
➜ ~
```

Comment: try and clear nmp cache, npm cache clear, and make sure you have permission to install ?

Comment: thanks where would I change permissions in this case?

Comment: running the command with sudo, because you when you are passing it the -g switch it means you are installing globally so you need to have super user rights.. So I think running the command with sudo hopefully should work

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli` you need sudo privileges when installing something globally, or remove the `-g` switch.

Comment: From my googling I am not sure why some systems require sudo or root access and others dont, my laptop for example doesn't require sudo for these commands with -g to run yet my desktop machine does? It seems very arbitary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid needing sudo with npm, there are likely going to be other permissions errors. Here is what I did after installing npm with sudo:

Uninstall NPM: `sudo npm uninstall npm -g`

Install NVM so that I can install npm without needing sudo (similar to RVM), see: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation

Install latest npm: `nvm install stable`

Clear caches `npm cache clear`

and then everything worked